# Lubuntu 20.04 - unable to conect to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, lubuntu

I installed lubuntu 20.04 from a live usb, dual boot with Windows 10. I don't know how I missed it it during installation, but both the live and installed version are unable to connect to wifi.

To be more specific, after boot, I get a notification that I was connected to a wifi, and clicking the connetion manager in the taskbar shows all available networks around correctly. However, after a few seconds, all wifis disappear, and nothing brings them back.

To me, the issue seem to be that `wlo1` is disabled.

```
sudo lshw -C network

*-generic DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: ff
   serial: 40:5b:d8:4d:3c:e1
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 66MHz
   capabilities: bus_master vga_palette cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-47-generic firmware=N/A latency=255 link=no maxlatency=255 mingnt=255 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:157 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a1200000-a120ffff
```

this can be confirmed with `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 40:5b:d8:4d:3c:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

(`state DOWN`).

One solution I found online was `sudo ip link set wlo1 up`, however that either immidiatelly finishes executing and fixes nothing, or after a short waiting returns `RTNETLINK answers: Operation already in progress`.

In similar questions, I saw people asking for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`, so here it is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
 0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
 1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little embarrassing, but after another couple of days and restarts, the problem fixed itself. I still don't know what the problem was, since the only thing I changed is that moved closer to the wifi router (but now, even if I go to my original location, everything works fine).

The only advice I can give to people with the same issue is to take a look at this: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and to - unlike me - use the wireless info diagnostic script: https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info